# How to get only the userInfo with ADAL library without first getting the code

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

So I need to get the `userinfo` so that I can retrieve the `uniqueID` object. 
The sample code I found are always two steps, send a request to get the code, and then use the code and the appID and appSecret to get the token, along with the userInfo object. Can this process be simplied to be one step? Perhaps just request the id-token using the openID connect, without needing to get the code first?

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Params["code"] != null)
        {
          var code = Request.Params["code"];
            AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(MicrosoftAuthBaseURL);

            ClientCredential clcred = new ClientCredential(MicrosoftAppId, MicrosoftAppSecret);

            AuthenticationResult acResult = ac.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, new Uri(RedirectURI), clcred).Result;

            SignInUser(acResult.UserInfo.UniqueId);  var accesstoken = AcquireTokenWithResource(resource: "https://graph.microsoft.com/");

            Response.Write(accesstoken);
        }
    }


    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetAuthorizationCode();
    }

    public void GetAuthorizationCode()
    {
        JObject response = new JObject();

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "response_type", "code" },
                { "client_id", "clientid" },
                { "redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8099/WebForm1.aspx" },
                { "prompt", "none"},
                { "scope", "openid"}
            };

        var requestUrl = string.Format("{0}/authorize?{1}", EndPointUrl, BuildQueryString(parameters));

        Response.Redirect(requestUrl);

    }
    public string AcquireTokenWithResource(string resource)
    {
        var code = Request.Params["code"];
        AuthenticationContext ac =
    new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", "tenantID"
                              ));
        ClientCredential clcred =
            new ClientCredential("clientID", "clientSecret");
        var token =
            ac.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code,
                       new Uri("http://localhost:8099/WebForm1.aspx"), clcred,resource).Result.AccessToken;

        return token;
    }
    private string BuildQueryString(IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();

        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            list.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", parameter.Key, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parameter.Value)));
        }

        return string.Join("&", list);
    }

    protected string EndPointUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", "https://login.microsoftonline.com", "tenantID", @"oauth2/");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use id_token to get some user's information. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens.

Besides, if you want to get id_token, you can use the API as below

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=<you app id>        // Your registered Application ID
&response_type=id_tokene
&redirect_uri=<>       // Your registered redirect URI, URL encoded
&response_mode=fragment                              // 'form_post' or 'fragment'
&scope=openid profile email                                      // Include both 'openid' and scopes 
&state=12345                                          // Any value, provided by your app
&nonce=678910                                         // Any value, provided by your app
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc)

Comment: I know, I can also use postman to get the token, I just do not know how to use the `ADAL` library to do that. In `ADAL` the user information is stored in the `UserInfo` object. Currently I need to use the `oauth2` flow, first get the code, the get the id-token.

Comment: You can request the id-token using the openID connect, without needing to get the code first. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-aspnet-webapp.

Comment: For some reason I do not want to use the Owin openID connect library here, I need to stick with ADAL, but with ADAL I simply just do not know how to do this one-step id token retrieval.